# How to use Vuforia with Vive Pro

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, htc-vive

I am trying to track an object by using vuforia and the headset camera of vive. (Vive pro) using Unity3d.
Vuforia lists "Vive" as supported camera. But at the same time a project that is using Vuforia does not work on PC( just target mobiles and tablets ). 
So how can I build my project to work with Vive.
I am confused! It Doesn't support PC and at the same time it supports vive!!! 
Any solution??
Good day.

Comment: where did you see that Vuforia lists vive as supported camera. I checked supported devices i can not see vive in the [list](https://vuforia.com/content/vuforia/en/devices.html)

Comment: I saw in the discussions of vuforia.

Comment: I saw it in the discussions of vuforia community. But don't mind. How to run any Eyewear. Is it need pc ? Vofuria doesn't run on pc!

Comment: You would build to Android or UWP. It is explained [here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Working-with-Digital-Eyewear-in-Unity.html) and [here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Vuforia-for-Digital-Eyewear)